# Why did the Trump administration hold a press conference in the parking lot of a landscaping company?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, media

[image]

I’m assuming we’re allowed to ask questions for events that happened recently, or in this case, very recent - this past weekend.

The picture on the right is clearly Rudy Giuliani, and I’m assuming the rest of it is not photoshopped. So, I’m wondering why did the 45th POTUS, a hotelier himself, decide that a parking lot is a good place to have a press conference — a “big” conference — at a parking lot?

My [research](https://www.complex.com/life/2020/11/donald-trump-four-seasons-total-landscaping-tweet?utm_source=twitter.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=complexmag) tells me that it was a conference for his legal team, to deny that they lost the 2020 Presidential Election and they booked this quixotic spot, between a mortuary and a porn shop, purely by accident. But they held it there anyway?

I’m wondering what “big picture” or background info am I missing? Couldn’t the administration just re-schedule or book another (more) suitable location? All jokes and sarcasm aside, no one is that inept. Therefore, I wonder if the purported mistake is true.

Which is why I’m asking, as per question, why did they have a “big” conference in such a location?

Comment: I don't have a source so I will write this as a comment instead of an answer. Supposedly the initial Trump tweet said 'press conference in Philadelphia at the Four Seasons' implying the famous/ expensive/ central hotel of that name which would have been a more normal location for a presidential press conference. But the hotel denied the press conference quickly after the tweet, so team Trump adjusted to some other 'Four Seasons'.

Comment: There's also speculation that the poll watcher - as a convicted sex offender - can't be too close to a school (which the hotel Four Seasons is) https://www.thedailybeast.com/daryl-brooks-giulianis-vote-fraud-witness-at-four-seasons-total-landscaping-is-a-convicted-sex-offender

Comment: I always find "why did X do Y" questions to be troublesome. Unless they said why, in which case, the question is kind of deletion-worthy. Or unless the person giving the answer has documented telepathy, the answer is going to be opinion based, again deletion worthy.

Comment: @puppetsock I generally agree with that, but in this case, they did issue an official explanation, which the top answer is based on. Whether that explanation is true or just an after the fact excuse is probably impossible to know, but the official story, at least, we can talk about

Answer (score 7):

Speculation in the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/07/us/politics/trump-books-four-seasons.html) is that it was selected because it was an outdoor location in a Trump-friendly part of town (Philadelphia, being a Democratic stronghold, doesn't have many of those).  Prior press conferences in more traditional parts of Philadelphia, such as outside a courthouse or outside the elections office, had been disrupted by the noise from pro-Biden protesters.

In response to the repeated comments of "someone got the names mixed up and scheduled at the wrong place", the timeline from the NYT article is:

- Giuliani arranges for a press conference outside Four Seasons Total Landscaping.
- Trump tweets "Lawyers News Conference Four Seasons, Philadelphia. 11:00 a.m"
- Trump tweets "Big press conference today in Philadelphia at Four Seasons Total Landscaping - 11:30am".

If there was any confusion, it was confusion on the part of Trump in his announcements, not on the part of the person arranging for the conference.

Comment: Did this company regularly rent out its parking lot?